# Difference between ReactiveMongo , Mongo-Module and MongoHelper

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

`Mongo` with `Play-Framework` is new for me. I have `Spring-Framework` background, In which we create `Controller, Business and DAO` layer structure applications. Now, i want to taste the flavor of `Play-Framework` with `ReactiveMongo`. For create our sample Application, my first target is to follow `Controller, Business and DAO` layer structure. `Play-Framework` already provide the basic structure of application, which is really good. If we use Mongodb with Play-Framework, I found three types of MongoDB Drivers. These are as below:

1. Mongo Module (https://www.playframework.com/modules/mongo-1.1/home)
2. MongoHelper (https://gist.github.com/harmeetsingh0013/fdc9c20b056a62f303f5)
3. ReactiveMongo(http://reactivemongo.org/)

`ReactiveMongo`, which is really awesome for implementing non-blocking I/O. In reactive mongo there are some problem with sync the data from multiple queries. I have some queries for creating sample application as below:

1. My first target is to implement MVC using `ReactiveMongo`, which i think `ReactiveMongo-Extension` provide me `Dao` layer. But i still want to confirm, `ReactiveMongo-Extension` is a good approach ? or I need to go for `MongoHelper`? What is the benefit of `Mongo-Module` over reactive mongo?
2. For dependency Injection we need to go for `Spring-Dependency Injection` or Guice or other `Scala Dependency Injection Framework` ?
3. If i am go for `ReactiveMongo`, we need to go for `JSONCollection` because `BSONCollection` is MongoDB Dependency. What is the support for `JSONCollection` available?

Comment: BSONCollection is from ReactiveMongo BSON lib. Even if you chose by design to go with JSON data exchange, BSONCollection will be there (in the core of RM).

Comment: Note that ReactiveMongo 0.11 is about to be release, with new ReactiveStreams support (with implementations provided for both Iteratee and AkkaStreams), client side SSL, and other features.

Comment: If you are interested in, here is a personal sample using Akka Stream prototype: https://github.com/cchantep/RM-AkkaStreams/blob/master/src/test/scala/CursorSpec.scala

Comment: @cchantep the last commit to ReactiveMongo is 15 days ago. Why is the development so slow? I am about to abandon ReactiveMongo-Extensions.

Comment: @fcs Last commit on PR is just few days old (end of last week). I would know call it slow. I think it can be discussed on the Google Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current modules repository on playframework.com is just for Play 1.x. So Mongo Module is not an option for you.

I am the author of ReactiveMongo-Extensions and it is highly inspired from MongoHelper. You can use which one you want. If you choose ReactiveMongo-Extensions JsonDao is your friend. There is also an example application which you can check out: https://github.com/mertkavi/play-reactivemongo-extensions-sample

BTW I am currently developing a newer driver from scratch. You may also give it a try:  https://github.com/fehmicansaglam/tepkin

Comment: Thanks @fcs, It means for DAO layer `ReactiveMongo-Extensions` is good option. But the thing is that, `ReactiveMongo-Extensions` is a part of `ReactiveMongo` driver? You are working on new drivers, what is the difference between, `ReactiveMongo` and `Tepkin` ?

Comment: ReactiveMongo and Tepkin share many ideas. But the main difference is while ReactiveMongo uses Iteratees, Tepkin is built on Akka Streams. Akka Streams will be default in the upcoming Play versions.

Comment: That's good. Thanks for your great support. The main challenge is, what actulay support for `ReactiveMongo-Extensions` or `Tepkin` have. How i actualy conges my seniors to move this technology ?

Comment: hey @fcs if you like, please join our chat room, for discussion, if you allow. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73074/scala-play-framework-and-reactive-mongo

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara Unfortunately I don't have time to join that room. But I actively participate in Tepkin gitter chat. And there are also other helpful devs there. https://gitter.im/fehmicansaglam/tepkin?utm_source=share-link&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=share-link

Comment: Thanks @fcs for you gitter chat room.